# Different Outputs for the same intent

Tags: javascript, node.js, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I'm getting different `@sys-time` outputs for the same intent `#what-time` when deployed on the server and when testing in the Watson conversation. Where am I going wrong here? The `context` variable is set to my Country `timezone`:`Asia/calcutta`. I have attached the image!

[image: screen shot]

Comment: In your screenshot, i don't see any difference in outputs. During the testing in watson conversation, the block with the green border it is debugging block. In your screenshot output from website is: 2017-06-13 08:57:33 and output from testing tool is: 2017-06-13 14:29:02

Comment: They were taken at the exact same time. The difference between them is 6hrs+

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the same problem a few weeks ago. And, you saw within the IBM Bluemix, Watson Conversation Service set the `context` variable `timezone`.
That is, you should do the same with the code.

**Within your application set the context variable timezone to your zone. Like:**

```
data.context.timezone = "America/Sao_Paulo"
```

Obs.: `Data` are the return from Watson Conversation Service (Intents, entities, context variables, etc)

This example is with Nodejs, but you can try using any Programming language.

**Check** **(**`timezone` **is set within the Conversation Service):**

[image]

**Check** **(**`timezone` **is set within my application with code):**

[image]

**EDIT(Where you add this code?)**:

```
//add inside your call, like:
conversation.message(payload, function (err, data) {
    data.context.timezone = "America/Sao_Paulo";
    if (err) {
      return res.status(err.code || 500).json(err);
    }
    updateMessage(payload, data, req, res);

  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But Where am I supposed to add this line : "data.context.timezone=' ' " ??

Comment: Inside the call for conversation service, if you're using nodejs, the [conversation simple](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-simple) have the `updateMessage` [function](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-simple/blob/master/app.js#L70), you can add inside this function, in this case, `response.context.timezone` :)

Comment: I added it this way : function updateMessage(input, response) {
  response.context.timezone="Asia/Calcutta";  //rest of the code follows} But it doesnt seem to work

Comment: Check my edit, you can add inside call for the conversation, like my example